# Correct URL to access webpage on xampp

Tags: url, ip, xampp, port

I installed xampp and made sure config file listens to port 80.
I forwarded the http port from the router to the correct computer ip. 
Now I am trying to access the index.html like this from another house http://myip:80
But it is not working. What could it be wrong?

Comment: Does it work via http://localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You must to have at least server with used ServerName in Apache config
Can't tell more while I don't know
 - Do you use virtual hosts
 - Which module, if use

In short - show you httpd.conf after comment "main" server configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows-System, try the following steps to find the bug:

- First of all, try to reach the host by using the ping-command.
- If this works, make sure, that the hosts-firewall ist not blocking incoming request to port 80.
- There are the following, necessary settings in your httpd.conf-file:

  - Listen 80
  - ServerName YourServer:80
    Try to use ServerName the same name as your Windows-Computername.
- It might be useful to know, if you run SKYPE, there's an option that allows Skype to use port 80 for communication. This might block the apache-service to run properly and maybe prevents the page from beeing accessed.

I hope, this helps!